# Fill input text forms on other website in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, input

I want to autofill textboxes on another website so I'm writing a short script to do this. I'm loading an iframe with a website in it and if this iframe is loaded, it should fill in the input text forms. So I wrote this in `autofill.php`:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="fill.js"></script>
<iframe name="autofillframe" src="https://e-services.blum.com/main/" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></iframe>
```

And this I wrote in `fill.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#username').val('username');
    $('#kennwort').val('password');
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZBwCm/1/)

If I do it with a .php file instead of a website, it works fine.
Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TKyvD/1/) without website

Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

When you load a page from a different domain into an `iframe`, you can't do *anything* to the iframe page from JavaScript in your page.

As far as the browser is concerned, the iframe is a separate window and you have no access to it. Imagine that the user had a banking page open in one window and your page open in another window. You know that the browser would not let your JavaScript code interfere with the banking page, right?

The same thing applies when the other page is in an `iframe`. It's still a completely separate browser window, it's just positioned so it looks like it's inside your page.

In your working example, the code works because the username and password fields are *not* in an `iframe` from a different domain. They are part of the same page that the JavaScript code is in.

If the `iframe` is loaded from the same domain as your main page, then you can do anything you want to it, including filling in form fields. The code would be slightly different because you need to access the `iframe` document instead of the main page document, but that's easy. But if the `iframe` is from a different domain, you are out of luck.

Comment: Hm okay, sounds logical. Is there another way or is this not possible?

Comment: Really no way at all, sorry! Browser security won't allow it.

Comment: Mh okay, what a pity. Thanks for supporting me :)

Comment: But how do widgets like chat services do it?  You copy a script tag and then it works on your site?

Answer (score 3):

By pressing submit button , input value copies from input textbox to iframe textbox (or opposit of it).
you can implement it like:

test1.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#submit').click(function(){
                var iframe = document.getElementById('myiframe');
                var doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
                var elem = document.getElementById('username');
                doc.getElementsByName('user')[0].value = elem.value;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="username">
    <input type="submit" id="submit">
    <iframe id="myiframe" frameborder="1" src="test2.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

And test2.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="user" id="user">
</body>
</html>
```